# Why select2 control don't pass his name (as normal input) with form submit?

Tags: jquery-ui, form-submit, jquery-select2

I have an input populated by Select2. However, when the form is submitted I cannot access the field's value (that is, there is no key with the Select2 field value).

How can I fix this issue, in order to be able to access the value of Select2 on the server side?

```
<form method="POST">
    <!-- this select is absent in POST params -->
    <div id="sel"></div>

    <!-- but this is present -->
    <input type="hidden" name="but_select2_absent" value="val1" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#countries_select').select2({
        ajax: {
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term
                };
            },
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/ajax/countries-provider",
            results: function (data) {
                return {results: data};
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [{"id":"1","text":"\u0423\u043a\u0440\u0430\u0438\u043d\u0430"},{"id":"2","text":"\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f"},{"id":"3","text":"\u041f\u0435\u0440\u04431"}]    -(it's output of /ajax/countries-provider)

Comment: yes, I can get the selected val by: $('#countries_select').val(). But Chrome network tab show me empty form.. And php's var_dump($_POST) too

Comment: I prepare an archive with complete example(extract to webserver folder). Form contains two fields, but only one ( input[text] ) is passed via POST. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13145912/select2.zip

Comment: I have deleted my comments in order to keep this short. I have edited your question and added the code (always add the relevant portion of the code to your question instead of a link to download - sometimes we can spot an error just by reading the code). Also added an answer that solves your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you don't have an `input` but a `div`

You should change the code

```
<div id="sel"></div>
```

To something like this:

```
 <input type="text" id="sel" name="sel" />
```

Otherwise, your form will not contain the input to be posted to the server. Furthermore, you have to give a name to the input, so it can be caught on the server side (as a matter of fact, if you don't give it a name, it will not be posted).

Comment: OMG, I was sure that .select2 do this itself.. You are the MAN!